# How can I check that whether a broadcast receiver is working or not?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Here is bootstartup.java file. I have checked that TestService is working properly. But I just want to know how can I check that data is broadcasted?

**Code**

```
public class bootstartup extends BroadcastReceiver {  

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        // start the service  
        Intent service=new Intent(context,TestService.class);                      
        context.startService(service);                    
        Log.e("com.example.myglobalbroadcastreceiver","Broadcast Received:"+intent.getAction());                         

        // start the app               
        Intent app= new Intent(context,Abhijeet.class);  
        context.startService(app);             
    }  
}
```

Comment: Umm, check the LogCat, as you put `Log.e()` there? If you set the manifest correctly, this broadcast will always be called upon device boot-up.

Comment: I have added an action of connectivity change in manifest file.
I just go to Data Usage and turn on the mobile data. I can see that the service is working. 


<action android:name=“android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE”   /> 


Is it the symbol of properly working of broadcast receiver?